# Convert text in PLPGSQL/Orafce

Tags: encoding, plpgsql, iso-8859-1, orafce

I'm working with PL/pgSQL and Orafce after a conversion from Oracle. In a function I'm writing in a file. I would like to write with the LATIN1 encoding. My database is in UTF8.

There is `convert` functions but I think I miss something because I don't seems to find my use case.

```
convert('testé', 'UTF8', 'LATIN1') ==> in BYTEA test\351
```

The problem is that this function returns `bytea`. How could I get a `text`?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you would actually need the `convert_to` function that converts a `text` from the database encoding to a `bytea` encoded in a different encoding:

```
SELECT convert_to('testé', 'LATIN1');

  convert_to  
--------------
 \x74657374e9
(1 row)
```

You cannot have the result to be a `text`, because that byte sequence would not be a valid UTF-8 encoded string, and PostgreSQL is unforgiving about this kind of data corruption.

Unfortunately orafce doesn't seem to offer a function to write binary data to a file, but perhaps `COPY` can help you:

```
COPY (SELECT textdata FROM texttable ORDER BY something)
   TO 'latin1file' (ENCODING 'LATIN1', FORMAT 'csv');
```

The only disadvantage is that `COPY` escapes certain characters like `"` and `,`, so you might need to choose a separator or delimiter that does not appear in your strings.

Comment: Yes I also tried convert_to, unfortunatly I have the same problem with bytea at the end. for the COPY function, I used it to export CSV files, but in my case, I rely on UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE multiple times in plpgsql functions, so how could I write in a FILE_TYPE with the COPY function ?

Comment: You won't be able to do it with orafce, because it does not support writing binary data, rigt?

Comment: Yes, so that's why I followed your advice, and I'll use the COPY command like that: `command := concat('COPY (',vl_param_query,') TO PROGRAM ''cat>>', vl_param_rapport_path, ''' WITH (ENCODING ''LATIN1'')');`   which is working fine. but the function accept 2 parameters, file UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE and content text. So now I have to find a way the get the filepath from UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE which doesnt seems to be possible

Comment: What is the `FILE_TYPE`?

Comment: Seems like it is just an integer representing a file, so my function look like that `prc_put_line (vl_param_rapport UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE, vl_param_string text )` and have to add a line to the report. So my workaround at the moment is to add the path of the file like that `set_config('utl_file.' || vl_outputfile, filepath, false);` in the function calling the prc_put_line function and get it back in the prc_put_line function with  `current_setting('utl_file.' || vl_param_rapport)`, but I'd rather find a more elegant solution

Comment: You could write your own C function, that might be easiest...

Comment: Yes thank you, that's a good idea, I'll dig into that